# How to save records in a multi model Ream database?

Tags: kotlin, realm

I have a project that uses 3 Realm models: Pantry, Department and Market. The Pantry and Department have a 1 to many relationship and the Pantry and Market have a many to many relationship, and all 3 are shown below.
The issue is that I (being new to Realm and to databases in general) am having dificulties saving and updating the models. In general the Pantry model saves well, but the other 2 don't.
The idea is: the Department saves many Pantry items, the Pantry item saves only 1 Department item. The Pantry item can save many Markets and the Market item can save many Pantry items.

When the database is totally empty saving the first item goes smoothly.

Then on entering a new item which falls on an existing and/or Market, a new item is created in the Department and Market models; instead of adding to the existing.

I have been unsuccessful in finding documentation on 1 to may and many to many schemas. I have found how to create the models and that's how I have created them but not how to use them for inputing records and how to save (housekeeping).

I tried querying for the existing department and market and when the query is successful and it is used on new items, the app crashes. I have followed it, by use of the debugger and by logs and all seems ok, yet the app crashes. I have not reviewed the general logs, since I would not understand anything unless its completely simple.

The models:

```
class Pantry: RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId()
    var itemName: String = ""
    var department: Department? = null
    var market: RealmList<Market> = realmListOf()
    var brand: String = ""
    var size: String = ""
    var price: String = ""
    var date: String = ""
    var checkToAdd: Boolean = false
    var checkChecked: Boolean = false
}

class Department: RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId()
    var deptName: String = ""
    var pantry: RealmList<Pantry> = realmListOf()

}

class Market: RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId()
    var marketName: String = ""
    val pantryItems: RealmResults<Pantry> by backlinks(Pantry::market)
}
```

The query to find the existing department:

```
fun checkDeptName(dName: String): Pantry? {

        val existingItem = realm.query<Pantry>(query = "department.deptName == $0", dName.lowercase()).first().find()
        if (existingItem != null) {
            Log.d("WALRUS", "Inside the function: ${existingItem.department?.deptName}")
            return existingItem
        }
        else {
            return  null
        }
    }
```

The query to find existing market:

```
fun getMarketByMarketName(marketName: String): Market? {
        val allPantries = realm.query<Pantry>().find()
        for (pantry in allPantries) {
            val market = pantry.market.find { it.marketName == marketName }
            if (market != null) {
                Log.d("WALRUS", "Inside the function: ${market.marketName}")
                return market
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

The function to add a new pantry item to the database:

```
fun addPantryItem(
        name: String,
        dept: String,
        myMarket: String,
        brandName: String,
        sizeName: String,
        priceName: String
    ){
        // Find the market by the name and update the pantry item
        Log.d("WALRUS", "Just Before saving the market item")
        
        val existingMarket = getMarketByMarketName(myMarket)

        val pantry1 = Pantry().apply {
            itemName = name
            if (existingMarket != null){
                Log.d("WALRUS", "Found existing market: ${existingMarket.marketName}")
                market = realmListOf(existingMarket)
            } else {
                Log.d("WALRUS", "Did NOT find existing market")
                market = realmListOf(Market().apply { marketName = myMarket })
            }
            if(brandName.isNotEmpty()) brand = brandName
            if(sizeName.isNotEmpty()) size = sizeName
            if(priceName.isNotEmpty()) price = priceName
        }

        val existDepartment = checkDeptName(dept)

        if (existDepartment != null){
            Log.d("WALRUS", "Found existing department: ${existDepartment.department?.deptName}")
 
            pantry1.department = existDepartment.department
        }else{
            Log.d("WALRUS", "Did NOT find Existing department")
            val department1 = Department().apply {
                deptName = dept
                pantry = realmListOf(pantry1)
            }
            pantry1.department = department1
        }


        Log.d("WALRUS", "Reached just before the vms.launch")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            realm.write {
                copyToRealm(pantry1, updatePolicy = UpdatePolicy.ALL)
            }
        }
        Log.d("WALRUS", "Reached the save pantry and ready to clear val's")

        //Clear all val's
        _itemName.value = ""
        _dept.value = ""
        _pantryMarket.value = ""
        _brand.value = ""
        _size.value = ""
        _price.value = ""
    }
```

I believe that is the relevant information.
The issue is to add 1 item, because adding items in bulk, is easy and no problems.
Here is a sample:

```
fun createSampleEntries(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            realm.write {

                // MARKETS
                val market1 = Market().apply {
                    marketName = "Keys-Food"
                }
                val market2 = Market().apply {
                    marketName = "Publix"
                }

                // PANTRY ITEMS
                val pantry1 = Pantry().apply {
                    itemName = "shampoo"
                    market = realmListOf(market2)
                    brand = "L'Oreal"
                }
                val pantry2 = Pantry().apply {
                    itemName = "deodorant"
                    market = realmListOf(market2)
                    brand = "Brut"
                }
                val pantry3 = Pantry().apply {
                    itemName = "earbuds"
                    market = realmListOf(market2)
                    brand = "Johnson & Johnson"
                }
                val pantry4 = Pantry().apply {
                    itemName = "sugar"
                    market = realmListOf(market1, market2)
                    brand = "Domino"
                }
                val pantry5 = Pantry().apply {
                    itemName = "water"
                    market = realmListOf(market1, market2)
                    brand = "Zephyrhills"
                }

                //DEPARTMENTS
                val department1 = Department().apply {
                    deptName = "toiletries"
                    pantry = realmListOf(pantry1, pantry2, pantry3)
                }
                val department2 = Department().apply {
                    deptName = "baking goods"
                    pantry = realmListOf(pantry4)
                }
                val department3 = Department().apply {
                    deptName = "beverages"
                    pantry = realmListOf(pantry3)
                }

                pantry1.department = department1
                pantry2.department = department1
                pantry3.department = department1
                pantry4.department = department2
                pantry5.department = department3

                copyToRealm(pantry1, updatePolicy = UpdatePolicy.ALL)
                copyToRealm(pantry2, updatePolicy = UpdatePolicy.ALL)
                copyToRealm(pantry3, updatePolicy = UpdatePolicy.ALL)
                copyToRealm(pantry4, updatePolicy = UpdatePolicy.ALL)
                copyToRealm(pantry5, updatePolicy = UpdatePolicy.ALL)
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason its easy is because the models are there ( pantry1, pantry2, department1, market1, etc).

But on a 1 item at a time, is a different story. I need to get back department1 and the market1.
How is it done. That is the question.....

Any guidance as to where to look for information on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The description of the code is a bit confusing and the way the code is described isn't what happens. For example *on entering a new item which falls on*  - what does *falls on* mean? Does it mean a new Market object is created? If so, creating a new Market object will not create a reference to it in the Pantry list; it would need to be added TO that list which would also create the inverse relationship. Secondly, there's WAY too much code, please reduce it. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that is that the 'item' is purchased in a particular 'market' or belongs under the a 'department' category. I don't create a new Market, it is somehow created; even though one already exists. That is the issue. About reducing the code, I will have to work on that. However, thank you for responding.

Comment: *'item' is purchased in a particular 'market'* - I assume 'item' means 'Pantry', not another object called 'item', right? If that's true, a `Pantry` can't be added to a `Market` directly as the relationship is inverse of that. However, a `Market` object *can* be added to a `Pantry`, which would then create an automatic inverse relationship from that `Pantry` back to the `Market` it belongs to. *I don't create a new Market* - but the code creates new `Market` objects - `val market1 = Market().apply` - and - `market = realmListOf(Market().apply`. Also, no inverse relationship from Pantry to Dept

Comment: I'm sorry @Jay; I am pretty confused. Yes when I say item, I mean a record in the Pantry model. So when a new record is added to Pantry, it requires a **'itemName'** a **'dept'** and a **'market'**. These in turn go to the **'Department'** and **'Market'** models. The issue is that (for instance) if **'Amazon'** already exists in the **"Market'** model, a new one should not be added in the **'Market'** model. Shouldn't Realm check that **Market.marketName** already exists and add the **Pantry.itemName** to it; or how is it supposed to be done ( by the coder)? I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: The terminology needs clarity; there is no such thing as 'creating a record in the Pantry model'; the Panty *is* the 'record' and it's not even a record; it's an object. So "create a new Pantry object" would be more accurate. Also, there is no 'requirement' for the itemName etc *properties* to be populated. It's often times best accomplished via a [convenience init](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/quick-start/#define-your-object-model). And, those in turn do NOT go the Department and Market models. Those are separate and need to be instantiated.

Comment: Oh "Amazon" would simply be a value of a property and nothing prevents duplicate values - other than your code. To update an object it needs to be read in, put into a write transaction and then the properties updated. I strongly encourage you to go through the Realm [Getting Started Guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/quick-start/) where there are coding examples and more. Take a look at [updating objects](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/update/) as well.

Comment: Ell, I'm really getting a learning experience with you @Jay. I will read up on those suggestions you have mentioned and get back to you if I have any other queries. Thanks again for your time Jay.

Comment: @Jay, I solved the issue. I read the links you sent me and found the solution. I learned about **managed** and **unmanaged** objects and that is what I was doing wrong. I was trying to use a managed object. Thank you Jay